# Selenium deletes chrome profiles

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

Selenium deletes chrome profiles. It happens ~1 in 30 times

My code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import os, sys, time, json, glob
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
import shutil,requests 
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument(r'user-data-dir=C:\Users\Danzel\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data')
chrome_options.add_argument(r'profile-directory=Profile 9')
chrome_options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")  # this
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-web-security')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-setuid-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--allow-running-insecure-content')
try:
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(),chrome_options=chrome_options)
except ValueError:
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager(version="116.0.5845.96").install(),chrome_options=chrome_options)
#driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver_autoinstaller.install(), options=chrome_options)
driver.implicitly_wait(1)

driver.get("https://www.google.com/")

#some code

driver.close()
try:
    [x.kill() for x in psutil.process_iter() if 'chrome' in x.name().lower()]
except psutil.NoSuchProcess:
    pass
```

And i get empty browser:
[image]

However, the profiles are still located in the \AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data folder:
[image]

why they were removed from the browser?

Comment: you're going to have a fresh config file/preferences for your Selenium session.  You'd have to explicitly tell the browser what preferences to write when launching.

Comment: @pcalkins, how can I do it?

Comment: not sure... you'd have to hack out the setting and pass the prefs in a prefs object... it's options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs); in Java.  Look at your default profile's preferences file to see what the option might be.